# Reroute From Direct URL to Partial unless from modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a bit of trouble stopping direct access to my partial pages. For example `Home/Create` I don't want accessible or would return them to `Home/Index`.

I can't seem to use the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute in the controller as it stops the partial appearing in a modal pop up which I use in conjuncture with jQuery.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the request is an ajax request or not and return/redirect based on that. Use the [`Request.IsAjaxRequest()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest(v=vs.118).aspx) method inside your controller aciton.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   {
     // return partial view
      return PartialView("Create");
   }
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Internally, this method will check the request headers and look for "`X-Requested-With`" header. When your call is an ajax call, the value will be "`XMLHttpRequest`"

***Side note***  : Angualar http service won't send this header [by default](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d). You need to explicitly enable it.

```
var app= angular.module('yourApp', []);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```